# Execute an action right after the user confirms registration

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I am using FOSUserBundle in my Symfony 2.3 project, and I want to execute some code right after the user confirms his account clicking on the email link. I was trying to override the

```
class RegistrationController extends ContainerAware 
{
...
}
```

but no luck :(

Can I create any kind of Event to be executed right after this action?

Thanks!

Comment: Override in the [RegistrationController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php) the function `confirmAction($token)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an EventListener which listens for `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED` like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;

class RegistrationConfirmedEventListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => 'performOnRegistrationConfirmed');
    }

    public function performOnRegistrationConfirmed(UserEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like performOnRegistrationConfirmed method is not executing the way I did, I created a new file RegistrationConfirmed.php in XXX/myBundle/Event/ and paste this code inside it. Am I missing something? Sorry I am new with Symfony 2. Thanks.

Comment: You have to [register the event listener as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#registering-the-listener). edit: I just noticed this isn't the best example and I can't find a better one right now. Just add your class to your `service.yml` and tag it with `name: "kernel.event_subscriber"`

Comment: Here is a better link: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#configuring-the-listener-subscriber